# iOS 7 Hide Quoted Messages in a Mail Thread

Tags: iphone, ios, email, gmail

Sometimes we have very long email discussions at work and thus email threads grow -- email clients automatically append all previous replies in the thread to your newly created message. (Gmail web app does that for sure, and that is what most people at my workplace use.)

The problem is, when I open such a thread in the Mail app on my iPhone it shrinks the text so that it can only be read without squinting if I turn the phone into the landscape mode. That happens because the app tries to fit everything -- including all the quote levels -- onto the screen. [image: Here is what is looks like.]

Can I somehow make the app zoom and reflow text or better hide those quoted emails? Gmail web app does that by default and offers you to click an ellipsis button ("...") to expand or collapse the quotes. I haven't find anything like in the Settings but maybe I'm just missing something. Anyway, I'd like to hear the opinions of the people who had encountered the same issue.

Well, I guess the best way would be perhaps to change settings so that quote level isn't increased automatically on each reply -- I've already done that on my iPhone but I would have a hard time convincing everyone to do so. Also I probably could install 
Gmail app for iOS but I would like to stick with the standard iOS app for it suits me in all other ways and I don't want to clutter my system with several apps that do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

[As of iOS 10](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/10/20/how-to-use-conversation-view-in-ios-mail-app/), the default behavior is for quotes at the end to be hidden under a "See More" button.

[image]